# Symfony 1.4 & ajax parameter "null"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, symfony-1.4

i'm trying to use ajax,but i cant reach my variables in my php.

On my symfony page i have :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "agenda/data",
   data: { title : title}
});
```

and in action.class.php => executeData function i try to get the parameter like that :
$title = $request->getParameter('title');
but it always return null . why?

how can i get my javascript variables into my action.class.php (i just want to insert them in db, and i don't want to get null parameter lol)?

Comment: But does title actually have value? Did you `console.log()` it?

Comment: yeah title have a value. (alert(title) show me the value before ajax call)

Comment: I think you need to check what else there is in request. Something like `$request->all()`, that will return all parameters.

Comment: @jylauril yes, but on the lastest version of symfony, i'm on 1.4.
-@-MaximKhan-Magomedov i will look at that after break launch.

Comment: @1nsan3 Yeah, just noticed that. It seems that best way in 1.4 is to specifically use `$request->getPostParameter('title')` instead.

Comment: i had already try it, it is the same thing.

Comment: @jylauril other ideas ? :s

Comment: @1nsan3 I think you should try to debug the ajax request first in your browser. Use either Firebug in Firefox or Web Inspector in Chrome/Safari to see the request it sends and see if all the parameters are in that request. If they are, then it's an issue on the PHP side.

Comment: all allright, it was just symfony cache... !

Comment: Heh, the cache is always the problem. Always disable cache when developing, that's my best advice. :)